# How to power two ESP-01S chips from 220 V AC

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage-regulator, esp8266, ac-dc

I would like to supply power for two [ESP-01S](https://www.shenzhen2u.com/ESP-01S-ESP8266-WIFI-MODULE) microcontroller chips. I am a beginner with such kind of circuits. There are some constraints:

1. The only available power source is 220 V AC, so I need an AC/DC converter from 220 V AC to 3.3 V DC.
2. The current draw of each ESP-01S chip is about 0.2 mA or the same order of magnitude.
3. The 3.3 V input pin for ESP-01S is Dupont, if I recognized it correctly. The power supply output should ideally have the same pin format (or it should be easy to solder this connector on the power supply output.)
4. The power supply must be compact (its PCB surface should not exceed 10 cm^2.)

Which kind of circuit, or which kind of device, could meet these requirements?

I am not looking for a specific purchase recommendation: I'm trying to understand if this is a common problem (as I guess) and how it is usually solved. It is a design issue.

Comment: There are plenty of commercial devices that have an esp8266 device and power supply. Some have an isolated power supply but most don’t. Have a look at the Tasmota project and it has a list of devices. One product that is available in Australia is a wifi switchable power outlet with usb charger. This is isolated.

Comment: Look for "Power Supplies - Board Mount / ACDC converters" at digikey.com

Answer (score 2):

The 2 most important rules of small/hobby electronics:

1. Don't mess with AC mains power.  It will kill you. *
2. Don't reinvent the wheel.  It will frustrate you and waste your time.

[image] [src](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Amazon-Basics-Port-Charger-White/dp/B0773BH9MB/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2P1CQHG7VBCZX&keywords=usb%20charger&qid=1655404171&refinements=p_89%3AAmazon%20Basics&rnid=669059031&s=ce-de&sprefix=usb%20charg%2Caps%2C185&sr=1-1) **

Now you only need to get from 5V to 3.8V.

The big boys are not exempt from this.  If you have noticed that *nearly every single piece of low-voltage electronics ever sold* comes with a "wall wart" power supply, now you know why.  Doing on-board mains conversion adds a very steep mountain of safety and regulatory issues. Whereas the simple use of an *already-approved* "wall wart" crosses all that off, and allows quick certification of their product.

* And I do AC mains power and understand the procedures and codes necessary. There isn't really a viable path to do it anyway. That's why everyone does the wall-warts.

** That CE mark actually means something this time.  This is not Amazon Marketplace crud from a 3rd party seller.  Nor is it other companies' products sold by Amazon (which due to Amazon Commingling, counterfeits can be snuck in). This is *Amazon's own product* and they have EU presence, so there's somebody to sue if the mark is faked.

Comment: Please provide a link or citation for the graphic you copied into your answer. The policy for this site is that answers should provide attribution for copied material.

Comment: @Elliot I chose the picture to be illustrative, not recommendable.  Since a link IS a recommendation, I'll have to change the picture to one I can actually recommend lol.

Comment: Thank you for your important advice. I got it. However, the voltage I must obtain is 3.3 V  (I think 3.8 V would be too high) and this would probably imply creating some additional circuit with a transistor. I prefer something (*already-approved*) which has already a 3.3 V output. Note also the problem with the pin shape: the image you posted would not be compatible with my connectors.

Comment: @BowPark that pin shape is standard Europlug, you can get other shapes. Smallest is Yankee NEMA 1-15. Main thing is, don't handle AC mains anymore than you have to, it'll reduce your liability and increase your ease of getting certifications such as UL or legit CE.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware to know the complete specifications of the supply of ESP-01.

[image]
from this [link](https://nurdspace.nl/ESP8266).

And for the need of only supplying ESP-01S, I choose some SMPS converters (google it "AC 220V 230V to DC 3.3V Step Down Converter Board Power Supply Module" ... that fit in a "well-closed" box (as a mains socket with a "non-functioning" board as wifi repeater ... already containing a functional power supply).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "wall wart" USB power supply with an LDO or buck regulator, or a power supply module, like this [MeanWell RS-15-3.3](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2547984.pdf) :

[image]

It is preferable to source it through an authorized distributor, as with any mains device going to dodgy sources can be risky from a safety point of view.

The module can supply up to 3A, which should be adequate (those chips draw several hundred mA when transmitting).